This weird algebra number theory question
Find all positive integers $n$ such that:
$n = \prod_{k=0}^{m} (a_k +1)$
where $a_ma_{m-1}...a_1a_0$ is decimal representation of $n$.

Now I tried for $m=0$ (Trivially Not possible), $m=1$ : $a_1a_0 = (a_0+1)(a_1+1)$, hence $a_1(9-a_0) = 1$
Hence $a_1 = 1, a_0 = 8$. So only possible scenario is $n = 18$.
Edit:
Trying for $m = 3$. Simplifying using algebra and then applying parity to eliminate 5 cases for 3 cases trying to use mod 4
I dont know how to proceed.
Pls help.
Thanks!!!!
Thanks to @Especially Lime to add the correct tags.
I am new

o sry lol but would like if i get some help here!!! :))

18 is the only solution. Checked programmatically + Especially Lime's answer.

Notice that $n$ has $m+1$ digits, so $10^m\leq n<10^{m+1}$. Also, the maximum possible value of $\prod_{k=0}^m(a_k+1)$ is $10^{n+1}$, if all digits are $9$. If we have too many digits less than $9$, then $\prod_{k=0}^m(a_k+1)$ will quickly get too small.
However, suppose we have even one digit $9$. Then $\prod_{k=0}^m(a_k+1)$ is a multiple of $10$, so we also have to have at least one digit $0$. Now the maximum possible value is only $10^m$, which is too small. (We know $n\neq 10^m$, since it contains a $9$.)
Therefore every digit is at most $8$. But for three digits, all at most $8$, the maximum value of the product is $729$, so we can't have three $8$s. You should be able to continue this argument to show that there are no three-digit solutions (and adapt it to show there are no solutions with more digits).

THANK YOU SO MUCH... i will ask if i could not procced

tried to proceed but hit quite a few blocks... and would be tough to solve it for variable m but i solved it now with a different method

i  used mod 10 and then simplified...
